# Could someone explain line 2 to line 9 of this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

```
def caesar_cipher(string, shift_factor)
  string.length.times do |i|
    if string[i].ord >= 97 && (string[i].ord + shift_factor) <= 122 || string[i].ord >= 65 && (string[i].ord + shift_factor) <= 90
      string[i] = (string[i].ord + shift_factor).chr
    elsif string[i].ord >= 97 && string[i].ord <= 122 || string[i].ord >= 65 && string[i].ord <= 90
      string[i] = (string[i].ord + shift_factor - 122 + 96).chr
    end
  end
  string
end
puts "Enter a string:"
string_input = gets.chomp
puts "Enter shift factor:"
shift_factor_input = gets.chomp.to_i
result_string = caesar_cipher(string_input, shift_factor_input)
puts result_string
```

https://github.com/OlehSliusar/caesar_cipher

A command line Caesar Cipher that takes in a string and the shift factor and then outputs the modified string.

I am unable to understand code line 2 to line 9. I am confused on how the .**times** method is used in this context. Could someone explain to me what is he doing from line 2 to line 9? How I understand **.times** method is that it act as a iterator as iterate based on the number time stated.

So say `5.times { puts "Dog" }` = > will result in putting "Dog" five time. Hence my understanding on the method **.times** is very different from the way the author used it.

Comment: SO users are lazy, we aren't likely to go to a link to look at code. Paste it here.

Comment: `.times` is used as intended here. "Run this loop as many times as there are chars in this string, and also pass current iteration index to the block". And then the block can do something with the passed index. In this case, it's doing the caesar cipher thing (change current char, `string[i]`, based on some logic)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Hi what does string[i] mean? in line 3

Comment: @roppo: current char

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment which does not answer the question (so no upvotes please).

That piece of code is ugly and arcane, not at all Ruby-like. Here's a another way that makes better use of Ruby's tools and is effectively self-documenting.

**Code**

```
def caesar_cipher_encrypt(string, shift_size)
  mapping = Hash.new { |h,k| k }.
                 merge(make_map('a', shift_size)).
                 merge(make_map('A', shift_size))
  string.gsub(/./, mapping)
end

def make_map(first_char, shift_size)
  base = first_char.ord
  26.times.with_object({}) { |i,h| h[(base+i).chr] = (base+((i+shift_size) % 26)).chr } 
end
```

**Example**

```
shift_size = 2
encrypted_str = caesar_cipher_encrypt("Mary said to Bob, 'Get lost!'.", shift_size)
  #=> "Octa uckf vq Dqd, 'Igv nquv!'."
```

**Explanation**

The first step is to create a hash that maps letters into their shifted counterparts. We begin with

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| k }
  #= {}
```

This creates an empty hash with a default value given by the block. That means that if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns `k`. Since all keys of 'h' will be letters, this means the value of a digit, space, punctuation mark or any other non-letter will be itself. See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

We then have

```
f = make_map('a',2)
  #=> {"a"=>"c", "b"=>"d", "c"=>"e",..., "x"=>"z", "y"=>"a", "z"=>"b"}
g = h.merge(f)
  #=> {"a"=>"c", "b"=>"d", "c"=>"e",..., "y"=>"a", "z"=>"b"} 
f = make_map('A',2)
  #=> {"A"=>"C", "B"=>"D", "C"=>"E",..., "X"=>"Z", "Y"=>"A", "Z"=>"B"} 
mapping = g.merge(f)
  #=> {"a"=>"c", "b"=>"d", "c"=>"e",..., "y"=>"a", "z"=>"b",
  #    "A"=>"C", "B"=>"D", "C"=>"E",..., "Y"=>"A", "Z"=>"B"} 
mapping['!']
  #=> "!"
```

We may now simply use the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that uses a hash to perform substitutions.

```
"Mary said to Bob, 'Get lost!'.".gsub(/./, mapping)
  #=> "Octa uckf vq Dqd, 'Igv nquv!'."
```

**Decrypting**

The receiver of an encrypted message can decrypt it as follows.

```
def caesar_cipher_decrypt(string, shift_size)
  caesar_cipher_encrypt(string, -shift_size)
end

caesar_cipher_decrypt(encrypted_str, shift_size)
  #=> "Mary said to Bob, 'Get lost!'."
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will explain it:

```
string = 'foo'
string.length.times {|i| puts string[i]}
```

Its a way of iterating through each letter in the string. They could probably do the same thing via:

```
string.chars.collect{|character| p(character)}.join
```

and have cleaner code as a result (where `p(character)` would be replaced by the required manipulation of the current character)

For example this code:

```
'foo'.chars.collect{|c| (c.ord + 1).chr}.join
```

Iterates through the string and returns a new string with each character replaced with the next one in the alphabet. That is: `"gpp"`

Comment: `.times` and index is used to _mutate_ the string. Could use `map` + `join` instead, or a number of other ways.

Comment: `.collect {|c| puts c}` - I don't think so :)

Comment: We think alike - I'd just updated my answer with `collect` and `join`

Comment: Ah yes - forgot that `puts` would not return the item being printed out.

Comment: Thanks this helps

Answer (score 0):

`.times do` means "execute this code a certain number of times" as you said.

`.times do |i|` loops a certain number of times and counts each time in `i`

`string.length` gets the number of characters in the string.

`string.length.times` executes a block of code a number of times equal to the number of characters in the string.

`string[i]` accesses the i-th character in the string.

Putting it all together:

```
string.length.times do |i|
    do_stuff_with string[i]
end
```

you have code which iterates through each character in the string and does something to it. in this case, the code shifts each character according to caesar cipher.

When you use iterators like `string.each_char` in ruby or `foreach(item in items)` in other languages, you're not generally allowed to modify the collection while you iterate. Using `.times` and `string[i]` lets the code modify the string while it iterates. because the loop doesn't keep track of string, it just knows that it needs to execute some number of times.

As others have pointed out, there are more elegant, more ruby-like ways to do what this code does, but the writer of the code chose `.times` because it acts just like a for-loop, which is a common programming paradigm.

Comment: actually why do string[i] accesses the i-th character in the string? this is not really intuitive to me, is there a reasoning or it is just like that.